# Hide part of a Flash animation in HTML

Tags: html, css, flash

I have an .swf file (a flash animation) that is too big and unfortunately we do not have the source code (the .fla file) anymore. I need to display it in a div, and want to hide part of it.

Any idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div style="width:100px; height:100px; overflow:hidden">
   <embed src="http://www.metacafe.com/fplayer/4133817/world_breakdancing.swf" width="400"  height="345" wmode="transparent" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowFullScreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" name="Metacafe_4133817"></embed>
</div>
```

Please note that wmode="transparent" is really important!

Comment: Hi Kirzilla, thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for. I should have come here earlier! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If the movie was compiled in `wmode=transparent`, it should be possible to give the `div` a fixed width and/or height, and apply `overflow: hidden`.

According to [**this**](http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=E5141), it will work in all current major browsers. In unsupported browsers, the full movie will be above all other page elements.

If the movie was not built `transparent`, I think there is no way to do this.